# What does if(); do, where the semi-colon is right after the parentheses?

Tags: php, if-statement

It happens that, when writing some PHP code, I accidentally put a semicolon `;` right after an if statement. For example:

```
if($a > 1);
{
   ....
}
```

I thought that PHP should raise an error in this case, but it is not. That kind of syntax should have a meaning, I'm just wondering what it is.

For what I could see the condition seems to be always true when the `;` is added but I'm not sure at all this is the meaning.

Comment: It works not because it has any divine purpose, but that it makes sense from a grammatical standpoint (or at least causes no parsing difficulties). Sometimes `for` loops need no bodies, although I'd prefer it written as `for($a;$b;$c) {}` with braces.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A single `;` can be read as an "empty statement" and

```
if($a > 1);
{
   ....
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if($a > 1)
    ;        // execute an empty statement if $a > 1

// then execute the following block of code.
{
   ....
}
```

> ***For what I could see the condition seems to be always true when the `;` is added***

It only seems like it since the block is executed regardless of the if-statement.

Comment: I think he's also asking why `if($a > 1);` by itself *should even be* valid syntax, and if so, what purpose it would serve. Edit: Or maybe that's not what he's asking, but I find that to be a more interesting question, anyway. :)

Comment: that's why the code between brakets get always execute, thanks for such a fast response

Comment: @Rob: you're right i was asking also for the meaning of `if($a>1);` but in think we have the answer here: such a syntax does nothing

Answer (score 1):

Adding the semi-colon essentially ends the if block before the braces. It isn't true, it's just that you don't do anything in the if.

Think about it like this, if you don't have braces:

```
if($a>1)
  echo "Yes";
echo "No";
```

does everything before the first semi-colon inside the if. So in your case, there is nothing before the first semi-colon, so nothing happens.